# how to make (icon + label)s in jQuery mobile app first page

Tags: jquery, icons

I want to make in the main/first page in jquery mobile app something like the main menu in mobile some icons and under each one its label

```
<a href="#sport"  id="btn1">
  <img src="images/sports.png" ;  float: center"/>
</a><br /> sports
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
`<figure>` and <`figcaption>`

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/place" alt="Macaque in the trees">
  <figcaption>A cheeky macaque, Lower Kintaganban River, Borneo. Original by <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/rclark/">Richard Clark</a></figcaption>
</figure>
```

here is the example

[On dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/5070433)

Comment: it did not work the caption was not below the image it was down and left

Comment: give figcaption{text-align:center;}

Comment: still not working i have many icon/png image and i need to label each one and the caption not exactly under the image